# Proving every derivative of $\sqrt\cos x$ is unbounded?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

This question is related to one I posted earlier today. I am $99$% sure the claim is true, and I can of course prove it for the first two or three derivatives, but I don't know how to jump to the infinite case. Is induction of some kind in order? I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I haven't thought this through carefully, but personally, I would try to use the mean value theorem...

Comment: @KennyWong, I had that thought but I'm not sure how to make it rigorous. Average change on the interval is infinite, so the function's derivative must be infinite at some point. Useful for convincing oneself it's true, but not much else :/

Comment: It suffices to show that the first derivative is unbounded on $(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ (why?)

Comment: Well I've done that. Why is it sufficient? I know you want me to figure that out myself, but I can promise you I've thought about it for a while.

Comment: @recursiverecursion instead of saying "function's derivative must be infinite at some point", you should have said "function's derivative is unbounded in this interval". The difference between "unbounded" and "has a point where it's infinite" is important.

Comment: Prove that for any function on a bounded interval, if its derivative is bounded then the function itself is also bounded. By contraposition, if a function is unbounded on a bounded interval then its derivative is also unbounded. Apply this recursively starting with the first derivative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $f:(a,b)\to\mathbb R$ is unbounded above and differentiable. Claim: $f': (a,b)\to \mathbb R$ is unbounded.

Proof: Let $n\in \mathbb N$. Our goal is to find $c\in (a,b)$ such that $ f'(c) >n$. Let $z=\frac{b-a}{2}$. Since $f$ is unbounded above, there exists $x\in (a,b)$ such that $f(x) > (b-a)n+f(z)$. Suppose $x>z$; if $x<z$, then the proof will work similarly (although $f'$ will be unbounded below), and if $x=z$, then we can choose some other $x$ that satisfies the inequality. Then by the mean value theorem, there exists $c\in (z,b)$ such that
$$f'(c) = \frac{f(x)-f(z)}{x-z} \geq \frac{f(x)-f(z)}{b-a} > \frac{1}{b-a}((b-a)n+f(z)-f(z))=n$$
Since this works for any $n$, $f'$ is unbounded. A similar claim holds if $f$ is unbounded below.

So, since $\sqrt{\cos x}$ is infinitely differentiable and since its first derivative is unbounded, it follows (using induction) that each higher derivative is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \sqrt{\cos x}\implies |f'(x)| = \dfrac{|\sin x|}{2\sqrt{\cos x}}$. We have: $|f'(x)| \to +\infty$ when $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}^{-}$, this is enough to show $f'(x)$ is not bounded.

Comment: Yeah, I can do that. But how do we show the nth derivative is unbounded? For all integers n?

Comment: A function with bounded derivative cannot be unbounded on a compact interval. This should be apparent from the Lebesgue differentiation theorem. Then your hypothesis is clear by induction.

Answer (score 0):

let $c=\sqrt{\cos 2x}$, $s=\sqrt{\sin 2x}$, $t=\sqrt{\tan 2x}$, and let $D$ be the differentiation operator w.r.t. $x$, so:
$$
\begin{align}
Dc &= -st \\
Ds &= \frac{c}{t} \\
Dt &= t^3+\frac1t
\end{align} 
$$
a little algebra, together with Leibniz' rule for differentiating a product, shows that as $x \to \frac{\pi}4$ and $t \to \infty$ the differential coefficient $D^n c$ is dominated by the term $-st^{2n-1}$